# Notify user when the procedure is complete

Tags: ms-access, vba, output

I have an Access VBA program which takes a while to complete. It shoots a MsgBox in the end, but there is no way to know about it when Access is minimized. I'd like Access icon on taskbar to blink (I think it blinks when standard query confirmation is required) or at least to restore the Access window so the user sees the resulting MsgBox.

For some reason these have no effect:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppRestore
```

Answer (score 1):

The commands for controlling the application windows are:

```
application.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize
application.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMinimize
application.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppRestore
```

It works here, so you may have to call `DoEvents` before the restore command.

Comment: I tried adding DoEvents both before and after that line, still it is not maximizing.

Comment: Do you call `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppRestore` before or after the `MsgBox` command?

Comment: Before (some more chars because of the dumb char limit)

Comment: If you remove the MsgBox, will the application window restore?

Comment: Nope it won't... Weird. Maybe there are other similar commands?

Comment: No, those are the commands. Try building from scratch a very simple app to check it out. Then expand this step by step to mimic your full application.